# How to handle Fragment to not load again when coming from another fragment in Navigation Component in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

**Scenario**: I have 2 fragments ProductList and ProductDetail in my nav graph. And when i click on any product it opens the ProductDetail fragment using findNavController.navigate() method.

**Problem**: The problem is when I go back from ProductDetail to ProductList fragment, the ProductList fragment reloads again and it also calls the api to fetch products list, which I want to avoid.

If anyone knows the reason behind it or the solution to this particular issue please let me know in comments.

Comment: Without seeing any code nobody will be able to make any kind of detailed recommendations. But..... You are most likely making an api call in `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()`, both of which are called each time you navigate to a new fragment. You need to find a way to only make that call when *you* want it to happen

Comment: But I want the ProductList fragment to not load again when coming from ProductDetail fragment. Do you know anything about that issue?

Comment: Well, stop calling the API in `onCreateView` or `onStart`

Comment: Okay, then where it is preferable to call the API @EpicPandaForce

Comment: `viewModel.init {}` using the `viewModelScope`

Comment: Hmm...alright. But what if I have to pass some data to the API request, then how can I pass that in viewmodel init{} ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer from somewhere, so I am posting the sample code to resolve the issue I am facing -

```
private lateinit var contentView: View

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    if (!::contentView.isInitialized) {
        binding = FragmentNewProductListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        contentView = binding.root
        
        // initialize your views or set click listeners or call apis
    }

    return contentView
}
```

Note: To elaborate, there is some internal bug in the navigation library where it draws the previous fragment from scratch when going back from another fragment. So as a workaround or temporary patch, what we can do is just check whether the view is already initialized or not, if yes then don't create it again.

Hope you understand the reasoning and answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should cache the fetch result locally, pull from the cache either during a fetch attempt or upon failure of a fetch attempt. This is a very common pattern on mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will definitely try to implement that. But the issue of List Fragment reloads again when coming back from Detail Fragment (when using Jetpack Navigation Component), is really an issue or there is some workaround or proper solution for it.